# MASM x86-64 scanf not reading spaces

Tags: scanf, x86-64, masm

I have simple 64 bit assembly program that we are doing for class. It is supposed to take user input (string) and return that string with lowercase letters into uppercase and uppercase into lowercase.

With what I have, it will read anything until it finds a space and this will not read anymore after that. So if I input "test", it will output "TEST". If I input "test Test" it will output "TEST". However, if I add spaces before the first word, it would output the first word but removes the spaces. For example: input "  TesT", output: "tESt".
Anyone know how I can go about fixing this?
Here is my whole program:

```
;Author: Keenan Kaufman
;Date: 10/20/2017
INCLUDELIB msvcrt.lib

printf PROTO
scanf  PROTO
exit   PROTO

.DATA
CRLF BYTE 0Dh, 0Ah, 0                           ;carriage return
msgHeader   BYTE    "Enter a mixed case string: ", 0
message     BYTE    20 DUP(0), 0
target      BYTE    SIZEOF message DUP(?), 0Dh, 0Ah, 0
msgformat   BYTE    "%20s", 0

.CODE
main    PROC
;Display request for user input
        lea rcx, msgHeader
        call printf

;obtain user input
        lea rcx, msgformat
        lea rdx, message
        call scanf


        lea rsi, message
        lea rdi, target

        jmp GETNEXT
GETNEXT:
        mov al, [rsi]
        cmp al, 0
        je  ENDCASE
        cmp al, 'z'
        ja  NOCHANGE
        cmp al, 'A'
        jb  NOCHANGE
        cmp al, 'a'
        jae TOUPPER
        cmp al, 'Z'
        jbe TOLOWER

TOUPPER:
        sub al, 32
        mov [rdi], al
        inc rdi
        inc rsi
        jmp GETNEXT
TOLOWER:
        add al, 32
        mov [rdi], al
        inc rdi
        inc rsi
        jmp GETNEXT
NOCHANGE:
        mov [rdi], al
        inc rdi
        inc rsi
        jmp GETNEXT
ENDCASE:
        jmp FINISH
FINISH:
        ;Display target
        lea rcx, target
        call printf
        lea rcx, CRLF
        call printf


        mov rax, 0
        call exit
main ENDP
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a *feature* of `scanf`.  Here is the Linux man page for scanf which, for the %s format, says:

> s
>   Matches a sequence of **non-white-space** characters; the next
>   pointer must be a pointer to the initial element of a character
>   array that is long enough to hold the  input  sequence  and  the
>   terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.  The
>   input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width,
>   whichever occurs first.

To do what you want, read the characters yourself directly from `stdin` using `read()`, `getc()`, or `fgets()`.

Comment: There's no 'precision' is scanf formats -- only printf formats.  There's no way to specify a minimum number of characters in the `s` conversion, and no way to get it read spaces.  A better approach would be `%20[^\n]`

Comment: @ChrisDodd I want my program to be able to read the white space so I am guessing now I should not have the s. Is there anyway I can use scanf and read whitespaces?

Comment: @ChrisDodd when I use %20[^\n] and hit enter after I type the string, it does nothing, like it is still trying to read more input.

Comment: Scanf is for reading *formatted* input, such as fields separated by spaces. Since you want to read unformatted input, use fgets or getchar.

Comment: @ChrisDodd:  Yep.  Fixed.

Comment: @KeenanKaufman: Note that the `\n` needs to be a literal newline inside the string in the assembler output, not a backslash and an `n`.  Your assembler may not process C escape-sequences the same way a C compiler does.  (In NASM, you have to use backquotes instead of double quotes to get C-style \ processing.  IDK about MASM.)  Anyway, you could `db "%20 [^", 0Ah, "]", 0` to assemble the ASCII newline byte using its numeric code.  (MASM doesn't accept `0xa` for hex)